# How do I get the system QFileDialog in Qt5?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, ubuntu-16.04, qfiledialog

I created file dialogs to select files within a Qt application. When migrating to Qt5 I encounter a regression, the file dialog is much poorer when linking against Qt5 rather than Qt4:

### Qt4

[image: Qt4 file dialog]

### Qt5

[image: Qt5 file dialog]

For example it is very hard for an user to navigate to the network mounted share directories.

The code is as simple as this:

```
QString path;
path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Pick a file"));
```

`QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` does not change anything.

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04, I have both nautilus (3.14.3) and nemo (2.8.7) installed. nemo is configured to be the default file manager:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Every other application seems to use the same dialog as the Qt4 file dialog screenshot.

How do I get the "old" file dialog in Qt5?

---

If I try with `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME= ./my_app` then I get this:

[image]

Comment: Somehow, the platform integration doesn't work in Qt 5. The `DontUseNativeDialog` option is incorrect: Qt 4 did use the native dialog, it seems. Perhaps Qt 5 wasn't built with the correct platform integration plugin, or such integration plugin doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Or, t looks like you're using a Qt version w/o the support for the Gnome (GTK?) file dialog...

Comment: I am using Qt5 binaries from the Ubuntu repositories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 – it is more of a workaround than an actual solution, though:

**Edit:** First make sure that the package `libqt5libqgtk2` is installed. It brings the GTK2 bindings for Qt5. If the package is not installed, the file choosers will look like the last screenshot shown in the question above.

Then, assuming you want to launch your application `my_app` from a terminal, launch it as follows (mind the space after `=`):

```
$ QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME= my_app
```

This is because, according to a [bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appmenu-qt5/+bug/1378935), there seems to be a problem with the Ubuntu package `appmenu-qt5`: the package forces Qt5 dialogs to become non-native as a side effect of explicitly setting `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5` via `/etc/profile.d/appmenu-qt5.sh`. Unsetting the platform theme via `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=` before launching your application changes this behavior locally.

**Edit:** When using the described approach, however, the global menu might not work in `my_app`.

Comment: This does not provide a solution (looks worse for me) but describes the problem more precisely!

Comment: @VictorLamoine Agreed that my suggestion is not an actual solution. I guess this could only be provided by fixing package `appmenu-qt5`. I hope it was of some help to you anyway. What do you mean by "looks worse for me"? Did you try?

Comment: Oh, I see. What I forgot to mention: Do you have the Qt5 GTK2 platform theme installed already? It is the package `libqt5libqgtk2`. The combination of both did it for me. If it also works for you, I will update my answer respectively.

Comment: Now, that is a solution! Thanks a lot. The global menu works for me

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Comment: As a final comment, you can even enforce this behavior directly in the code, by setting (or unsetting) the environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` from there. In Python, using PyQt5, this would look as follows: `os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME"] = "";  app = QApplication([]); ...`. Don't know if that is a good idea though.